# Hide and reveal checkbox options - Tidy up Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, code-cleanup

So I am a relative novice to JS and the Jquery library. I have been playing around with something and can see it is extremely untidy, this is where I was hoping you guys could help suggest a better way of doing what I am trying to acheive.

Aim:

To have multiple checkboxes, some of which if selected reveal a sub set of checkboxes. If the parent is unchecked the children checkboxes should also become unchecked.

HTML (this is simplified)

```
<div class="option1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionA" />
    <div id="suboption1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="optionA1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="optionA2" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionB" />
    <div id="suboption2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="optionB1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="optionB2" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionC" />
    <div id="suboption3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="optionC1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="optionC2" />
    </div>
</div>

<!--No sub options on some-->
<div class="option4">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionD" />
</div>
```

JS

```
/*Option 1*/

$("#suboption1").hide();

$("#optionA").click(function() {
    revealOptionA();
});

function revealOptionA(){
    if($('#optionA').is(":checked")) {
        $("#suboption1").show('hide');
    } else {
        $("#suboption1").hide('hide');
        $("#optionA1").attr('checked', false);
        $("#optionA2").attr('checked', false);
    }
}
revealOptionA();

/*Option 2*/

$("#suboption2").hide();

$("#optionB").click(function() {
    revealOptionB();
});

function revealOptionB(){
    if($('#optionB').is(":checked")) {
        $("#suboption2").show('hide');
    } else {
        $("#suboption2").hide('hide');
        $("#optionB1").attr('checked', false);
        $("#optionB2").attr('checked', false);
    }
}
revealOptionB();

/*Option 3*/

$("#suboption3").hide();

$("#optionC").click(function() {
    revealOptionC();
});

function revealOptionC(){
    if($('#optionC').is(":checked")) {
        $("#suboption3").show('hide');
    } else {
        $("#suboption3").hide('hide');
        $("#optionC1").attr('checked', false);
        $("#optionC2").attr('checked', false);
    }
}
revealOptionC();
```

I have put together a quick JSFiddle to better demonstrate!

https://jsfiddle.net/j5pdq8p8/2/

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In short your second requirement of **If the parent is unchecked the children checkboxes should also become unchecked** will work if you replace `attr` with `prop` - https://jsfiddle.net/j5pdq8p8/11/

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will take this into account, Aneesh' example below uses this as well and he has reduced the code a huge amount as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added class for parent checkbox and the container div which have all child checkboxes. Using this way we can reduce js code.

Please check the below code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="option1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionA" class="parent"/>
    <div id="suboption1" class="child">
         <input type="checkbox" id="optionA1" />
          <input type="checkbox" id="optionA2" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionB" class="parent"/>
    <div id="suboption2" class="child">
         <input type="checkbox" id="optionB1" />
          <input type="checkbox" id="optionB2" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionC" class="parent"/>
    <div id="suboption3" class="child">
         <input type="checkbox" id="optionC1" />
          <input type="checkbox" id="optionC2" />
    </div>
</div>

<!--No sub options on some-->
<div class="option4">
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionD" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".child").hide();
$(".parent").change(function(){
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        $(this).parent().find(".child").find(":checkbox").each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
    $(this).parent().find(".child").hide();
  }
  else {
        $(this).parent().find(".child").show();
  }
});
});
```

For reference I have created this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/j5pdq8p8/17/)

Comment: This is perfect! The code reduction is great as my live version actually has about 20 options so you have saved me a heap of time!

Comment: @Tomatron : thanks.. Please accept the anser if your issue is solved.. :)

Comment: I also thought you wanted the `children` to be checked also if the `parent`is checked @Tomatron

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE - Not in this instance as the user may not require all of the sub options.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example with classes instead of id
(updated with uncheck on parent-option click)

**JS** then **HTML**

```js
$(".suboptions").toggle();

$('.options').on("click", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".suboptions").toggle();
  $(this).siblings(".suboptions").children().prop( "checked", false );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="options" />
  <div class="suboptions">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="options" />
  <div class="suboptions">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="options" />
  <div class="suboptions">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
<!--No sub options on some-->
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="options" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is not even related to the question

Comment: I thought he wanted a better way to do it... :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding to your question, you have 2 requirements,

1. To have multiple checkboxes, some of which if selected reveal a sub set of checkboxes.
2. If the parent is unchecked the children checkboxes should also become unchecked.

I believe you have done first already and asking for help to implement two,

I created a fiddle for second implementation,

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5pdq8p8/8/

**Use `prop` instead of `attr` for toggling `checked` or `disabled` property in `jquery`**

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code. And I UPDATED your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5pdq8p8/13/)

```
/*Option 1*/

       $("#suboption1").hide();

        $("#optionA").click(function() {
            revealOptionA();
        });

        function revealOptionA(){
          if($('#optionA').is(":checked")) {
                $("#suboption1").show('hide');
                $("#optionA1").attr('checked', true);
                $("#optionA2").attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $("#suboption1").hide('hide');
                $("#optionA1").attr('checked', false);
                $("#optionA2").attr('checked', false);
            }
        }
revealOptionA();

/*Option 2*/

       $("#suboption2").hide();

        $("#optionB").click(function() {
            revealOptionB();
        });

        function revealOptionB(){
          if($('#optionB').is(":checked")) {
                $("#suboption2").show('hide');
                $("#optionB1").attr('checked', true);
                $("#optionB2").attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $("#suboption2").hide('hide');
                $("#optionB1").attr('checked', false);
                $("#optionB2").attr('checked', false);
            }
        }
revealOptionB();

 /*Option 3*/

       $("#suboption3").hide();

        $("#optionC").click(function() {
            revealOptionC();
        });

        function revealOptionC(){
          if($('#optionC').is(":checked")) {
                $("#suboption3").show('hide');
                $("#optionC1").attr('checked', true);
                $("#optionC2").attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $("#suboption3").hide('hide');
                $("#optionC1").attr('checked', false);
                $("#optionC2").attr('checked', false);
            }
        }
revealOptionC();
```